# How can I change smart object opening software

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

How can I change smart object opening software...means when we double click on smart object link it will open in Microsoft office picture manager. It is possible I have done only the changes. But now I have completely forgot the procedure.I need to change it again to illustrator. Please help.

---

Thank you all guys for giving me response. But if it is not possible then why it is now opening in Microsoft office picture manager!!
Even though pasting a graphics done in illustrator still its opening in Microsoft office picture manager. That's the problem. I want to open it in illustrator as smartobject behaves with vectors.

Comment: Hey Anu, I don't think there's a way to change which program opens a smart object, it will automatically try to open it in the program the smart object was created in. Do you have Illustrator installed already? (Possible duplicate of this question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27388/open-photoshop-smart-object-in-illustrator-instead-of-photoshop)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're running this on a windows machine; have you set the default program in Windows? In Windows, right-click on one of the assets and select "Open with...". Select Illustrator from the list (you may have to surf for it) and make sure the "Always use this application" (or "use this app for all  files" depending on Windows version).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are talking about having a smart object in Photoshop, that when you double click it takes you to its native program. If the smart object was originally an EPS, and your computer settings are to open all eps files in Office picture manager, than that will happen.

**To solve this, you will have to open the native file in illustrator first and copy the vectors you want and paste them into Photoshop, OR just save the file as an illustrator file first, then drop it into Photoshop.** When you double click the smart object, it will open in illustrator again.

Comment: Still  it is opening in Microsoft office picture manager